# glewInit() Causes memory leak according to valgrind

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, glew

I am trying to debug and fix all memory leaks in my program. I have went through the entire source code and there is not one call of `new` or `malloc()` which isn't supported by a `free()` or `delete`. I tried running the program in valgrind. Valgrind found that a consistent(throughout multiple executions of the program) 844 bytes of data were definitely lost. It also constantly points me back to the glewInit() function of my Window class. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Couple things to note:

- My window class is completely static
- My window class calls `InputManager::init()` which is also a static class
- I have another completely static class for storing constants

```cpp
class Window {
public:

     // void create(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const std::string& name, bool resizable, bool decorated){
    //
    // }

    static void create(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const std::string& name, bool resizable, bool decorated){

         if(!glfwInit()){
              Utils::log("Failed to initialize GLFW");
            return;
         }


         //Setting Window settings
         glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RED_BITS, 8);
         glfwWindowHint(GLFW_GREEN_BITS, 8);
         glfwWindowHint(GLFW_BLUE_BITS, 8);
         glfwWindowHint(GLFW_ALPHA_BITS, 8);
         glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS, 24);
         glfwWindowHint(GLFW_STENCIL_BITS, 8);
         glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DOUBLEBUFFER, GLFW_TRUE);
         glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
         glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
         glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
         glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
         glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, resizable ? GLFW_TRUE : GLFW_FALSE);
         glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, decorated ? GLFW_TRUE : GLFW_FALSE);

         m_width = width;
         m_height = height;

    #ifdef __APPLE__
         glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    #endif

         //Creating the window
         window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, name.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
         if(!window){
              Utils::log("Window: Failed to create window");
            return;
         }

         //Settings for window
         glfwSwapInterval(1);
         glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, windowResized);

         //Creating the context for opengl
         glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

         //Initializing glew
         if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
              Utils::log("Window: Failed to initialize glew");
         }

         //Enabling transparency
         glEnable(GL_BLEND);
         glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

         //Enabling depth
         glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
         glClearDepthf(1.0f);

         //Enabling back face culling
         glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
         glCullFace(GL_BACK);

         //Enabling MSAA
         glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

         InputManager::init(window);

    }
     static void clear();
     static void update();
     static void close();

     //Window functions
     static void setVerticalSyncEnabled(bool enabled);
     static void setMouseCursorGrabbed(bool grabbed);
     static int getWidth();
     static int getHeight();
     static bool isResized();

     static bool isCloseRequested();

     static GLFWwindow* window;


private:

     static void windowResized(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);

     static int m_width;
     static int m_height;

     static bool m_isResized;
     static bool m_closeRequested;


};
#endif
```

Comment: OpenGL seems to be known for leaking (but it's probably under control - they know it won't leak until the program ends). You can create valgrind suppression files if you don't find any already made. Many libraries that leaks on purpose (like OpenCV, ncurses, OpenMPI, ...) supply valgrind suppression files with the library. They are usually called `something.supp`. I didn't find any for OpenGL though, but there are nice guides online for how to make one yourself.

Comment: Interesting.. well then that's relieving. So I guess this is a problem that I can ignore?

Comment: I react just like you and find "my" leaks disturbing and wanting to plug them. When I read about a library and find that the leaks are there and they are not considered to be bugs, but on purpose because the OS will clean it up, I try to get suppression files in place. Ignoring a library's valgrind output may be hard and often comes in the way of finding ones own problems. If I cause a leak and it's hidden somewhere in 100000 lines of library leaks, I may miss it.

Comment: That is very clever. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started using GLAD and it stopped causing the memory leak.